# ionic 4 local notifications when app closed

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I need to call my local notifications at a predefined time. This is working when my app is not closed. but once I closed the app, the notification is not working.

Answer (score 2):

have you resolved this issue?
What you can try:

1. check if your app autostart/notification permission is enable.

   > Sometimes, depending on your device model, the autostart permission is
   >   disabled by default, so if the application is closed you can not
   >   receive notifications.
   >
   > I had the same issue before.
2. Go thru this thread, where one user commented

> On Mi4, with or without the every, after the app is exited,
>   notifications not received.
>
> On Samsung S5, with "every" notifications stopped after the app
>   exited. Seems to be fine if scheduled without "every".

3. As stated in [katzer](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications)

> It might be possible that the underlying framework like Ionic is not compatible with the launch process defined by cordova. With the result that the plugin fires the click event on app start before the app is able to listen for the events.

So, what has work for me is to set in app.component.ts:

```
window.skipLocalNotificationReady = true;
  subscribeLocalNotifications() {
    this.localNotifications.on('click').subscribe((notification) => {

    });
    this.localNotifications.on('trigger').subscribe((notification) => {

    });
    this.localNotifications.fireQueuedEvents();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

- First you have to make your app can run at the background when you close your app.
- Second you have to schedule the local notification through the condition you want. `E.x: When you don't have wifi connection , push the notification with user`
  Did you use `cordova-plugin-local-notifications`?

Comment: I'm struggling in app run in background. can you help me with it? Yes I'm using cordova-plugin-local-notifications

Comment: so you haven't made it run in background yet , right ?

Comment: this is the example maybe match with your goal: https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode/tree/example

Comment: If you have any questions , tell me. i will try